# Broken Universal Link banner on Safari

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios-universal-links

The Universal Link banner for an app I am working on does not show up correctly.

[image: Screenshot 1]

As you can see, the label with the website name is missing. This is my `apple-app-site-association` file:

```
{
    "applinks": {
        "apps": [],
        "details": [
            {
                "appID": "Y6LR8R2J69.com.emcoders.PonzApp",
                "paths": [
                    "*"
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

The syntax is correct – otherwise the banner would not show up in the first place. Furthermore, it looks exactly like any other website where the banner shows up correctly (e.g. IMDb).

Is it something I have to configure on the app? Some ‘name parameter’ I might have forgotten to specify? Although it seems weird, I have looked up some tutorials and they are doing exactly what I did…

Comment: any ideas how to disable it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently the app needs to be published on the App Store with the right entitlements before the banner shows up properly. Until then, the test versions (ad-hoc builds or through Test Flight) will not make the system show up the proper banner.

Answer (score 0):

Since I can't find any documentation about that, I'm pretty sure that the banner title displays the App Store title of your app.

[image]

[image]

That means as long as you're installing the app from Xcode and not from the App Store the title won't show up.

Hope that helps.